# how to append text to a file in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Everytime this function is called the old text data is lost?? Tell me how to maintain previous data and appending new data.

This function is called 10 times:

```
void WriteEvent(LPWSTR pRenderedContent)
{
    HANDLE hFile; 
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = ((DWORD)wcslen(pRenderedContent)*2);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

    printf("\n");

    hFile = CreateFile(L"D:\\EventsLog.txt", FILE_ALL_ACCESS, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS,   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);                 

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to open file \"EventsLog.txt\" for write.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Writing %d bytes to EventsLog.txt.\n", dwBytesToWrite);

    bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                    hFile,                // open file handle
                    pRenderedContent,      // start of data to write
                    dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                    &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                    NULL);            // no overlapped structure

    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite)
        {
            printf("Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrote %d bytes to EventsLog.txt successfully.\n",dwBytesWritten);
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You should pass `FILE_APPEND_DATA` as the `dwDesiredAccess` to [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx), as documented under [File Access Rights Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116.aspx) (see sample code at [Appending One File to Another File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363778.aspx)). While this opens the file using the correct access rights, your code is still responsible for setting the [file pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364397.aspx). This is necessary, because:

> Each time a file is opened, the system places the file pointer at the beginning of the file, which is offset zero.

The file pointer can be set using the [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx) API after opening the file:

```
hFile = CreateFile( L"D:\\EventsLog.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0x0, nullptr,
                    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr );
if ( hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
    printf( "Terminal failure: Unable to open file \"EventsLog.txt\" for write.\n" );
    return;
}

// Set the file pointer to the end-of-file:
DWORD dwMoved = ::SetFilePointer( hFile, 0l, nullptr, FILE_END );
if ( dwMoved == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER ) {
    printf( "Terminal failure: Unable to set file pointer to end-of-file.\n" );
    return;
}

printf("Writing %d bytes to EventsLog.txt.\n", dwBytesToWrite);

bErrorFlag = WriteFile( // ...
```

---

Unrelated to your question, the calculation of `dwBytesToWrite` should not use magic numbers. Instead of `* 2` you should probably write `* sizeof(*pRenderedContent)`. The parameter to `WriteEvent` should be constant as well:

```
WriteEvent(LPCWSTR pRenderedContent)
```

Answer (score 11):

The parameter for appending data to a file is FILE_APPEND_DATA instead of FILE_ALL_ACCESS in the CreateFile function.
Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363778(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430.aspx) is a 16-bit Windows function. It does not support opening a file in append mode.

Comment: The document behind the link contains a call to `SetFilePointer` or `SetFilePointerEx`.  Even if you open the file with `FILE_APPEND_DATA` you must call one of these functions.

Comment: It's not necessary to call `SetFilePointer()`. Passing `FILE_APPEND_DATA` to `CreateFile()` causes the file pointer to be moved to the end automatically, which seems an undocumented behavior. (Have you tried?)